# What kind of hand grenade are the Death Troopers using in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, rogue-one

In Rogue One (movie) in several scenes a hand grenade is used by the Death Troopers.

[image: DeathTrooperAndGrenade]

I was thinking in that universe it would be a form a plasma grenade but I have no idea.

Comment: I assumed you meant the grenades used by Death Troopers so edited a picture of it in to make it clearer. Feel free to roll back if these are not the grenades you meant (you will need to remake the correction of Rogue from Rouge though)

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn those of the ones

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the film's [Visual Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide), they're ***fragmentation grenades.***

[image]

> **MERR-SONN MUNITIONS FRAGMENTATION GRENADE**
>   The C-25 fragmentation grenade consists of a sphere of baradium-impregnated detonite encased in a conductive shell. The shell itself is housed within a cyclinder - activated with a twist.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Beat me to it! damn you work"!!!

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn - I've treated myself to a hand-scanner to allow me to get these into digital format a lot quicker than using a flat-bed or taking a picture with my fridge.

Comment: @Valorum The lengths people go to get 250k rep!

Comment: Can I just say, "detonite" is the best name for an explosive material I've come across. Unless somewhere they have "baradium-impregnated explodium" devices.

Comment: @ench - in the real world we have "thermite" which is a wonderful word, redolent with relevant meaning.