# What is the name of this grenade used in the Jedha ambush in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, object-identification

[image]

I can't find any pictures or information on this grenade. It was used by one of the Partisans to indicate the start of the ambush.

Comment: It doesn't appear to have a canonical name. The *Rogue One Official Novelisation* just describes it as "a grenade" and it doesn't appear in the *Rogue One: Visual Dictionary*, nor the *Star Wars: Rogue One: Rebel Dossier*.

Comment: Could be an "IED", Improvised Explosive Device, or more colloquially "a pipe bomb".

Comment: I checked the post-RO games, doesn't seem to be in Battlefront II, Galaxy of Heroes, or Jedi: Fallen Order. The novelization describes it as a "metal sphere", so it may have changed models late in production.

Comment: Wait, I think I've seen a name for this before. Looking...

Comment: Someone on Twitter could probably just ask the LFL Story Group guys there and pray for a response. I’m not on Twitter any more, otherwise I would.

Comment: It's name is 'Poppy'

Answer (score 15):

**It doesn't appear to have a canonical designation, suggesting that it's some kind of homemade device, possibly a "canister explosive"**

Given that the Partisans are variously described as sporting a wide range of "*black market*", "*highly customised*" and "*slapped-together*" weapons, it doesn't appear that they have access to official weapon purchasing channels, suggesting that the grenade is an improvised device rather than something out of a catalogue from the likes of Merr-Sonn or Sienar.

The [*Rogue One Visual Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide) doesn't identify it specifically, but we do learn that their weapons, and particularly their explosives, are built by one of the Insurrectionists named [Weeteef Cyu-Bee](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Weeteef_Cyu-Bee) for their own use, noting that he's seen sporting something that looks very similar to the grenade used in the ambush.

[image]
<sub><sup>"He custom-builds the sticky-bombs used but the insurrectionists against the Imperial patrols of AT-ST walkers and tanks"</sup></sub>

This is also backed up in the (canon) *Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy* factbook which describes him as making "sticky bombs and **canister explosives"**.

> **Fiery Surprise:** *Explosives expert Weeteef Cyu-Bee, one of Gerrera’s Partisans, crafted sticky bombs and canister explosives for the insurgents to wield against Imperial patrols and vehicles.*

---

Interestingly, the grenade (identified in the novelisations only as "*grenade*") was originally scripted as a "*metal sphere*" but this appears to have been changed during production, possibly to make it look more improvised.

> Jyn didn’t see who threw **the first grenade**. She heard it strike
> pavement despite the noise of the vehicles, recognized the sound
> despite the murmuring from the rooftops and the sharp commands of the
> stormtroopers. A glint of sunlight drew her eye to the metal sphere
> and she saw it bounce once, roll half a meter in the direction of the
> tank, then disappear in an eruption of street fragments and smoke and
> shrapnel.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: Interesting. Either there was intent at one time for the grenade to maybe be a RotJ-ish thermal detonator, or someone thought because we managed to see one bomb one time, that every bomb in SW has to be like it.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - My gut instinct is that they wanted to make them look like a ragtag army of individuals, using improvised weaponry. Having them tote a pipebomb-looking grenade certainly adds to that feelings, especially when contrasted with the [sleek spacey-looking grenades that the Imperials use](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-25_fragmentation_grenade).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a Fragmentation Grenade. I haven't seen any reference outside of this card in Star Wars: Destiny (a TCG):

[image]

Does this look like the right thing?

Comment: This picture shows what appears to be a slightly downgraded version of the [C-25 grenades](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-25_fragmentation_grenade) used by the Death Troopers in Rogue One. Black, with a red stripe in the middle, centred around a twisting explosive mechanism. Nothing like the green pipe-bomb looking affair in the film.

Comment: That's [a different one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/152050/19561).